# Running an application in iPhone developed in XCODE

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, jailbreak

I need to run the application that I have made in Xcode on my iPhone. It works fine in simulator. I have a developer's account but I don't have iPhone SDK. Here is the tricky part:

I developed the application with iOS SDK using Cocoa-touch. now all those jail break things won't work there. I don't have a folder such as /Developer in my Mac Mini.

Please help me to run it in my iPhone to test how it looks on a real device and not on a simulator.

NOTE THAT I DON'T HAVE iPHONE SDK hence all the jailbreaking technique is not working. Or at least I am not able to implement.

Comment: Not sure what jailbreaking has to do with anything here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a developer's account but i don't have iPhone SDK

Use your developer account and download the iPhone SDK.

Comment: Is there a way to run the application without downloading iPhone SDK ?

Comment: @PradipTripathy Why would there be?

Comment: Kinda rhetorical question. Thanx mate.

Answer (score 0):

Even your basic free Apple Developer Account will allow you to download the latest version of the iOS SDK.  If you have the paid version, then you can download all versions.

Obviously, you need to download the SDK to have the code run.  The SDK is what makes the app run in the first place.

What I don't understand is that you say that you want to put the app on your iOS device, not on the simulator on your computer.  Doesn't your device already have the SDK installed on it? It has to.